# UNPIVOT a query that uses FULL OUTER JOIN and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an Account and Income tables and i am trying to combine and then unpivot them.

here are the values in each table:

**Income:**

[image]

**Accounts:**

[image]

I've gotten as far as summing everything up and calculating the difference with the following sql statement:

```
SELECT        SUM(Income_tbl.Income) AS Income, SUM(Accounts_tbl.Amount) AS Debt, SUM(Income_tbl.Income) - SUM(Accounts_tbl.Amount) AS difference
FROM            Accounts_tbl
FULL OUTER JOIN Income_tbl
ON Accounts_tbl.id = Income_tbl.id
```

and this is the result:

[image]

What i want to do is unpivot this by adding a "type" column that will hold the Income, Debt and difference fields and a "AMT" column that holds the amounts.

so something like this:

[image]

**Thanks all!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple `union all`?

```
select 'income' type, sum(income) amt from income_tbl
union all select 'debt', sum(amount) from accounts_tbl
union all select 
    'difference', 
    (select sum(income) from income_tbl) - (select sum(amount) from accounts_tbl)
```

Possibly, SQL Server would optimize the query by executing each subquery just once. Otherwise, you can still use a cte:

```
with cte as (
select 'income' type, sum(income) amt from income_tbl
union all select 'debt', sum(amount) from accounts_tbl
)
select * from cte
union all select 
    'difference', 
    sum(case when type = 'income' then amt else -amt end) 
from cte
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that a `full outer join` is correct for this, but that it not your qustion.  But, just use a subquery:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT SUM(i.Income) AS Income, 
             SUM(a.Amount) AS Debt, 
             SUM(i.Income) - SUM(a.Amount) AS difference
      FROM Accounts_tbl a FULL OUTER JOIN
           Income_tbl i
           ON a.id = i.id
     ) ai CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Income', Income), ('Debt', Debt), ('Difference', difference)
     ) v(type, amt);
```

It is probably much more efficient to do:

```
with ai as (
      select 'income' as type, sum(income) as amt
      from income_tbl
      union all
      select 'debt', sum(amount) as amt
      from accounts_tbl
     )
select ai.*
from ai
union all
select 'difference',
       sum(case when type = 'income' then amt else - amt end)
from ai;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1 as [type],col2 as [amt] FROM
(
SELECT  SUM(Income_tbl.Income) AS Income,
SUM(Accounts_tbl.Amount) AS Debt,
SUM(Income_tbl.Income) - SUM(Accounts_tbl.Amount) AS difference
FROM  Accounts_tbl
FULL OUTER JOIN Income_tbl ON Accounts_tbl.id = Income_tbl.id
) stu
UNPIVOT
(col1 FOR col2 IN ([Income],[Debt],[difference])
) AS tbl
```